# Calling Methods on object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, eval, global

I have a question regarding global variables I guess.

I have the following code:

```
$('span.ion-chevron-left, span.ion-chevron-right').click(function() {

    var myIterator  = $(this).attr('data-iterator');

    ('ion-chevron-right' == $(this).attr('class')) ? window[myIterator].next() : window[myIterator].prev();

    if(!window[myIterator].valid()) {

      (window[myIterator].key() == window[myIterator].getTotal()) ? window[myIterator].rewind() : window[myIterator].end();

    }

    // do something

});
```

You need to know that the variable myIterator holds a string like 'myIterator1', 'myIterator2', 'myIterator3'...

As you can see I want to avoid redundance. I don't want to write something like this:

```
if('myIterator1' == myIterator) { ... }
if('myIterator2' == myIterator) { ... }
```

So I am trying to call methods on different iterator objects by writing window[myIterator].method();

Is this the right way to do it? I figured it would be possible to use eval, but I red that eval is evil so is there a difference? Or how would one solve this kind of problem? Are there any security concerns in my current code?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach is sound, but you should avoid polluting the global namespace by putting your iterators in a dedicated object. Instead of `window[myIterator]`, use (for example) `iteratorDict[myIterator]`, which `iteratorDict` is defined by

```
var iteratorDict = {
    "myIterator1": ...,
    "myIterator2": ...,
    ...
}
```

Or, if you don't want to define all of them at once like that, simply change your definition `var myIterator1 = ...` to `iteratorDict["myIterator1"] = ...`

Comment: I really like your answer. I impolemented your suggestion like this:

var itDict = new Object();
itDict['foo'] = ...

Access:

itDict[myIterator].next();

I hope this is good practice and this is not a critical implementation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3180943 Yes, that looks good. You can shorten `var itDict = new Object();` to simply `var itDict = {};` if you like.